# button.enable not refreshing IOS

Tags: ios, button

I have a UIViewController loading data from web, the process takes about 15 secs, So I put my long running process on 2nd thread, when the 2nd thread is completed, i will set the button enable or disable. but the button is not refreshing when the process is done.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FunctionNSObject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

NSMutableArray *schoolsAvaliable;
NSDictionary *dict;
NSString *schoolNameCh, *schoolNameEn;
int schoolYear, schoolID;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //initial set the button disable
    self.button.enabled = NO;

    //2nd thread
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loadSchool", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

        //get avalible school info from JSON
        schoolsAvaliable = [FunctionNSObject loadDataFromWeb:@"http://some web service"];

        //get school year
        schoolYear = [FunctionNSObject getSchoolYear];


        if (schoolsAvaliable.count != 0)
        {

            //select the first row from array
            dict = schoolsAvaliable[0];

            //get the value from dictionary of that row
            schoolID = (int)[[dict objectForKey:@"SchoolId"] integerValue];
            schoolNameCh = [dict objectForKey:@"SchoolName"];
            schoolNameEn = [dict objectForKey:@"SchoolNameEn"];

            self.button.enabled = YES;
            [self.button setNeedsDisplay];

        }
        else
        {
            self.button.enabled = NO;
            [self.button setNeedsDisplay];

        }

        //2nd thread end then
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //[self.pickerSchool reloadAllComponents];
            self.labelSchool.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d",schoolYear,schoolYear+1];

            NSLog(@"%d",self.button.enabled);

        });

    });



}


@end
```

Comment: Only main thread can modify UI.

Comment: Are you using iOS 7.1? Can you try this on 7.0 (simulator should be ok). I recently came across an issue on iOS 7.1 which causes the button's UI not change on enabled state changes.

Comment: As visput and others have pointed out, you need to do all UI manipulation on the main thread.  Also, note that the way you're declaring schoolsAvailable, etc. will result in them being global variables.  You need to enclose those declarations in {} to make them instance variables.

Comment: yes, only happen in 7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call related to UI methods on non-main thread. Usually it results to unpredictable behaviour.
Try to call methods related to UI on main thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.button.enabled = YES;
});
```

As [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3203487/david) noticed you needn't call `[set.button setNeedsDisplay]` because call of `setEnabled:` method results to call of this method.

Comment: Shouldn't need `setNeedsDisplay` as `setEnabled:` will automatically call it.

Comment: @David I got code from initial question for correspondence but you are right, I will remove it from answer.

Comment: end up i create a global boolean variable , and set it in 2nd thread, and check this boolean variable , then set the button enable or disable in main thread. thx guys !